# Javascript regular expression for english & numeric characters only

Tags: javascript, regex

What is the easiest way to check if an expression has English or number characters only? with no spaces and no other characters.

p.s - the first character cannot be a number. upper or lower case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would use: `/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/`. Here are same examples:

```
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test("expression");
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test("EXPRESSION");
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test("e123xpression");
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test("E123xpression");
/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9]*$/.test("1expression");
```

Without boundaries (`^` and `$`) regexp match any substring too.

EDIT: Updated invalid expression

Comment: probably type, because it does not work, 'expression' seems to be valid string but `/^[A-Za-z][A-Zaz0-9]*$/.test("expression");` returns false, change `..az..` to `..a-z..`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. That was typo. I've just fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

Easiest:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*$/i
```

explanation of the expression:

- `/` - open expression
- `^` - string must start here. Nothing before
- `[a-z]` - find only one character between a to z, including
- `[a-z0-9]*` - find any sequence of characters either between a to z including, or between 0-9 including (the "any sequence" part is the * in the end)
- `$` - string must end here. Nothing after
- `/` - close expression
- `i` - the expression is case insensitive

tested with the following cases

`var tests = //key = case, value = expected results
     { "joe"          : true //only lower case
     , "JOE"          : true //only capital
     , "charsAndCaps" : true //mixed case
     , "ABC444"       : true //caps and numbers
     , "AAaaAA3276"   : true //mixed case with numbers
     , "111Joe"       : false //starts with number
     , "112345"       : false //only numbers
     , "asaaa$"       : false //non-alphanumeric char in the end
     , "asaaaלא"      : false //non-latin char in the end
     , "asaaнет"      : false //non-latin char in the end
     , "#asaaa"       : false //non-alphanumeric char in the start
     , "לאasaaa"      : false //non-latin char in the start
     , "нетasaa"      : false //non-latin char in the start
     , "aaלאasaa"     : false //non-latin char in the middle
     , "sssнетaa"     : false //non-latin char in the middle
     , "as&&aaa"      : false //non-alphanumeric char in the middle
     , ""             : false //empty string
     }`

try it at:
http://jsfiddle.net/erJ4H/161/

Answer (score 3):

try this one:

```
/^[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i
```

add some examples:

```
/^[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i.test("check#$#"); // false
/^[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i.test("1check"); // false
/^[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i.test("check1"); // true 
/^[a-z][a-z\d]*$/i.test("cHEck1"); // true
```

Answer (score 3):

> /^[A-Za-z\d]+$

```
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("TEST1"); // true
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("Test2"); // true
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("test3"); // true 
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("4TEST"); // true
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("5Test"); // true
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("6test"); // true 
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("TE7ST"); // true
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("Te8st"); // true
/^[A-Za-z\d]+$.test("te9st"); // true
```

Comment: requirement not met: 1st char cannot be numeric

Comment: @RadagasttheBrown are you mean starts with characters? /^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z\d]+$

Comment: Ah, Aywa, mazboot :)

Answer (score 2):

Use this: `[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

try this `/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*$/i`